# Can we use the word North to refer to all of Europe including southern Italy?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The way I see it is that the default position of the world is the equator, and thus Europe could be referred to as the "North", but I am wondering if I am stretching the meaning of the word too extremely. What are your thought on this? Because the meaning is pretty much relative to who the speaker is, I am a bit perplexed about this.

> I laid to rest on Mount Etna, as the humans call it, a mountain of the
>   North.

Comment: Everything north of the equator is called 'the northern hemisphere'. Portugal, Spain, Italy, the Balkans and Greece are called 'Southern Europe'. Give a full sentence and then we can judge whether you use 'north' appropriately.

Comment: If the meaning depends on who (or more likely, where) the speaker is, then how can this question be answered without knowing that?

Comment: Africa can certainly call it that way. For Greenland it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I am wondering if there's a sort of default equator rule if there's no speaker and it's impersonal.

Comment: It's kinda hard to come up with a sentence when I meant it in an impersonal way where some God describes Italy as being in the North.

Comment: To give a sense of just how relative this is: Palermo, Italy (almost as far south as one can go in Europe) is at a higher latitude than Evansville, Indiana. This puts almost all of Italy *north* of almost all of the US "South".

Comment: Thanks for adding the sentence. As a stand alone sentence it sounds really bizarre to say Mt Etna is a mountain of the north. Maybe if the surrounding context is a story about Tunisia (immeditaely to the south) or South Africa (way to the south) , then 'north' might be OK. But most any other context, you'd just say 'the primary mountain/volcano of Sicily'; anything else would sound weird.

Comment: What exactly are you afraid you're stretching?  North?  The North? north? And are we in the real world or an imaginary one?   In the US, people living in Maine do not refer to New York as "the South".  These words,  when capitalized and with "the", are not  relative.  They have absolute conventional meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are billions of people who live south of Mount Etna.  To them, Mount Etna is in "the north."

If the population of humans this figure is referring to live in, say, Egypt, then they might reasonably call Mount Etna "the mountain of the north."

Likewise, a site that is far to the south of where most of us live could be called "the north" by anyone south of that location.  For example, Uluru is a rock formation in central Australia.  Central Australia is south of most of the rest of the world, but it's north of all of the biggest cities in Australia. Someone in Sydney could call Uluru "the mountain of the north."

In fact, almost every location on Earth can be called "the north." The only place that cannot ever be north of your location is the South Pole.

Answer (score 1):

if you are refering to the northern hemisphere, then yes, indead, the entirety of Europe, is in the northern hemisphere. However, if you are referring to the north of europe, Northern Europe is the general term for the geographical region in Europe that is approximately north of the southern coast of the Baltic Sea. Nations usually included within this region are Denmark, Estonia, the Faroe Islands, Finland, Iceland, Latvia, Lithuania, Norway and Sweden, and less often the United Kingdom, the Republic of Ireland, northern Germany, northern Belarus and northwest Russia.

Comment: I provided an example sentence as people requested it.